# CSS: Linking to a section in page without the id persisting to the URL?

Tags: html, css

Is it default behavior in CSS to for the section id to persist to the url of my site?

For example:

```
<a href="#section"></a>

<div id="#section">links to this section</div>
```

However after I link to this section, the id **#section** persists and stays appended to the url regardless of what page I am on.

For example, I can navigate to another page and it's still there in the url mysite.com/about-us/**#section**

Is there a way to stop the #section from appending to the url after click in CSS?

Comment: "I can navigate to another page and it's still there in the url...". It's really still in the url on another page?

Comment: Could you put up a working snippet illustrating the problem because from the description I can't see the #section persisting whatever I do to link to another page.